# Increasing maximum number of Apache solr facet blocks

Tags: 6, search

**Installation Details**

- I have installed [apachesolr](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) module in Drupal 6.
- The version of Apache Solr is 1.3.
- Number of facet blocks enabled via **admin/settings/apachesolr/enabled-filters** as well as from **admin/build/block/list** are 30.

Currently I am facing following issues

- Whenever I select options from more than 4 facets, apache solr doesn't return any result and it throws a message "***The Apache Solr search engine is not available. Please contact your site administrator.***"
- If I add more facet block via
  **admin/settings/apachesolr/enabled-filters** as well as from **admin/build/block/list**, apache solr stop work altogether and throws the message "***The Apache Solr search engine is not available. Please contact your site administrator.***" .

I guess this is an issue with Apache Solr Settings i.e. increasing the maximum limit of facet blocks. But I don't know what those settings are.

Comment: Have you taken a look at your solr logs? The application itself might be able to tell you what goes wrong with the query. Failing that, the query log might reveal useful information.

Comment: @kekkis I checked the logs but there is nothing in log files.

Comment: Well I suspect there is something going wrong with the query anyway. You can try getting your hands on the query (if no query logs, then you need to tweak at least one file), then run that query through your browser to see what goes wrong.